# How to make the Chewie video player responsive - Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've tried to place inside *SizedBox*, also use *AspectRatio* property but it does not working properly. If I can adjust the size to suit on mobile devices, it won't be responsive on tablet. This code is placed inside a *Column*

```
Chewie(
  controller: chewieController,
),
```

This is how it's declared:

```
 videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(
        "https://player.vimeo.com/progressive_redirect/playback/738271412/rendition/1080p/file.mp4?loc=external&signature=b4ac532ca6f446de3a53ba9e29a5d7e54f3bca0acb5ae61528a44d75222a0ef8");

    //videoPlayerController.initialize();

    chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController,
      autoPlay: true,
      looping: false,
    );
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try put your widget into Expanded widget:

```
Expanded(
    child: VideoPlayer(),
);
```

or into:

```
final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

SizedBox(
    width: screenSize.width,
    height: screenSize.height,
    child: VideoPlayer(),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved by adding *SizedBox* widget

```
SizedBox(
              width: 80.w,
              height: 40.w,
              child: Chewie(
                controller: chewieController,
              ),
            ),
```

and aspectRatio inside constructor

```
chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController,
      autoPlay: true,
      aspectRatio: videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio*2,
      looping: false,
    );
```

This is suited for my example, because the video width is twice bigger than the height, but it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that worked for me (chewie v1.5.0).

The key addition (compared to other suggestions I'd seen) was to add a Container with max constraints (provided by a LayoutBuilder).

```dart
LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          _chewieController != null && _chewieController!.videoPlayerController.value.isInitialized
              ? Container(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(
                    maxHeight: constraints.maxHeight,
                    maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth,
                  ),
                  child: AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: _videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio,
                    child: Chewie(controller: _chewieController!),
                  ),
                )
              : const SomeFallBackWidget(),
        ],
      );
    });
```

I also passed the aspectRatio to the chewie controller:

```dart
_chewieController = ChewieController(
        videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController,
        \\... other options
        aspectRatio: _videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio,
        );
```

Note: I got some misalignment in how the chewie controls were rendering when adding SafeArea and AppBar in the parent Widget. The solution that worked for me was  `SafeArea` > `Scaffold(extendBodyBehindAppBar: true)` > `Stack` > `...as above` (with no AppBar).